# How to execute these series of commands in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

How can I execute these series of commands in batch file? It only executes the first line which is the `sqlcmd -S ********\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P *****`:

```
sqlcmd -S ********\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P *****

USE Database
GO
SELECT * FROM TBLPERSON
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command.

```
SQLCMD -S <server> -d <database> -U <user> -P <password> -Q "SELECT * FROM TBLPERSON"
```

Check out the SQLCMD documentation for more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017).